# Most efficient way to check to see if there is any data in a SQL row

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

The code below works, but I know it can't be the most efficient.  Is there another way to ask if there are any rows rather than using Any()?

I'd like to have the NoResults Div hidden by default and only turned on when no rows are present, likewise have the repeater show up by default and only hidden when no results are listed.

```
using (AgileEntities context = new AgileEntities())
        {
            int StoryID = Convert.ToInt32(Request["StoryID"]);
            var tasks = from t in context.Tasks
                        where t.StoryId == StoryID
                        orderby t.Number
                        select t;
            rptTasks.DataSource = tasks;
            rptTasks.DataBind();

            if (tasks.Any())
            {
                rptTasks.Visible = true;
                NoResults.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                rptTasks.Visible = false;
                NoResults.Visible = true;
            }


        }
```

Comment: to add to my answer below - also you can just check Count() directly - but again beware to do this on the list to make sure you don't execute the query twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var tasks = from t in context.Tasks
                            where t.StoryId == StoryID
                            orderby t.Number
                            select t;

    var tasksList = tasks.ToList();

    rptTasks.DataSource = tasksList;
    rptTasks.DataBind();

    if (tasksList.Count > 0)
          {
                rptTasks.Visible = true;
                NoResults.Visible = false;
          }
          else
          {
                rptTasks.Visible = false;
                NoResults.Visible = true;
          }
```

The ToList() call will execute the query and create a list of tasks objects

Comment: I would rewrite anything here. If there is no data the repeater won't show anyway so there is no need to toggle the visibility. On the repeater's DataBound event I would count its Items to see if is empty and I would toggle there the no results div. Of course .Net has a ListView control which deals very nicely with this.
 I would move the query in other class( actually in other dll). Instead of the SQL statements in code behind, now we see LINQ. Jon Harding, please don't take this as an offence at your code.

Comment: The repeater has a header and footer template, so if no results are listed, I'd like to hide those as well. No offense taken at all.  The code I had worked, I'm new to .net and want to become better! The if statement to hide/show the two items seems like a lot of code for very little results.  Is there a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: It depends on the html you need to create. I'm very happy with the ListView control, it can be used as repeater also, and it has a template for the situation when the datasource is null or the list is empty. I'm using the repeater also, but if I need to things like this one you do I would go with a ListView Control. My comment was more a reaction to a previous comment to my answer, unfortunately deleted, which was saying something about the if statement, that it needs to be re-factored.

Answer (score 2):

Caution - calling .Any() may re-execute your query 
I would do this a bit 'safer' to ensure single execution.

```
//force execution once
var taskList = tasks.ToList();
rptTasks.Visible = taskList.Count>0;
NoResults.Visible = taskList.Count==0;

And
 rptTasks.DataSource = tasksList;
 rptTasks.DataBind();
```

The problem with Any() and Count() is they cause your code to execute over and over - a test case

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            //Populate the test class
            List list = new List(1000);
            for (int i=0; i  o.CreateDate.AddSeconds(5) > DateTime.Now);
            while (newList.Any())
            {
                //Note - are actual count keeps decreasing.. showing our 'execute' is running every time we call count.
                Console.WriteLine(newList.Any());
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
}
```

You can replace Any() with Count() above to show. Basically the code keeps evaluating the query when you call Any() - I'm not sure if this applies to Linq to Sql though if there is any different caching mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can change this with :

```
rptTasks.Visible = tasks.Any();
NoResults.Visible = !rptTasks.Visible;
```

Comment: The idea is not to send to queries to the server. First one is sent at the rptTasks.DataBind() and the second one at if (tasks.Any()). So is not about re-factoring the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataBind()` call has already caused the query to be executed, so calling `Any()` on top of that shouldn't cost you anything further.

Comment: I believe is the query is executed twice.